# Nightmare creating a self-signed SSL certificate that works

Tags: ssl, iis, tls

I have an intranet server that I need to install a SSL.

This is the `openssl.cnf`

```
[ req ]
default_md              = sha256
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
attributes              = req_attributes
req_extensions          = req_ext
#prompt = no

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = US
countryName_min                 = 2
countryName_max                 = 2
stateOrProvinceName             = CHICAGO
localityName                    = CHICAGO
0.organizationName              = MY COMPANY
organizationalUnitName          = IOS DEVELOPMENT
commonName                      = server2.myserver.local
commonName_max                  = 64
emailAddress                    = bob@example.com
emailAddress_max                = 64

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword               = password
challengePassword_min           = 4
challengePassword_max           = 20

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth

[alt_names]
DNS.1   = server2.myserver.local
DNS.2   = myserver.local
```

This is the commands I am using to create it.

1. generating the root CA key

   ```
   openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootCA.key 4096
   ```

2.this is generating the root CA certificate

```
openssl req \
    -x509 -new -nodes \
    -key rootCA.key -sha256 \
    -days 825 \
    -out rootCA.crt \
    -subj /CN=server2.myserver.local \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -extensions SAN \
    -config <(cat ./openssl.cnf \
        <(printf '[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:server2.myserver.local')) \
    -extensions 'req_ext'
```

3. generating the certificate key

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out mydomain.com.key 4096
   ```
4. generating the certificate

   ```
   openssl req -new -sha256 -key  mydomain.com.key \
    -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=server2.myserver.local" \
    -reqexts SAN \
    -config <(cat ./openssl.cnf \
        <(printf "\n[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:server2.myserver.local,DNS:myserver.local")) \
    -out mydomain.com.csr
   ```
5. converting the CA cert to p12

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out ca.p12 -inkey rootCA.key -in rootCA.crt
   ```
6. converting the certificate to p12

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey mydomain.com.key -in mydomain.com.crt
   ```

Then I install `ca.p12` and `certificate.p12` on my IIS server and on my devices.

When I try to visit `server2.myserver.local`

I get

[image]

How in the name of Saint Certificate do I do that?

Comment: You added both certificates to Firefox?

Comment: Going by the OU name you are developing for Apple devices.  You should avoid `.local` domains - see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207511

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your root CA certificate is completely wrong. CA certificates are very different from end host TLS certificates – you cannot use the same config for both.

- Don't put the server's domain in the subject – that's useless. If it's a CA, it should just have `CN=My internal CA` or something like that.
- Add the `basicConstraints` extension. It must say that the certificate is a CA.
- Add the correct `keyUsage`. You need to have 'keyCertSign' and (just for completeness) 'cRLSign'.
- Don't add `subjectAltName`. The certificate is for an authority/issuer, it's not for the server!
- Don't add `extendedKeyUsage`. It is sometimes used to constrain what certificates the CA can issue, but it's better to start off without this complexity.
- Good idea to add `subjectKeyIdentifier`, in case you later end up having multiple internal CAs with identical subject DNs. (Normally CA DNs must be unique, but having SKI/AKI kinda relaxes this.)

So you should have a "CA" config file that looks more like this (and stop adding SANs and other stuff through command line – that's what the config is for):

```
[ req ]
default_md              = sha256
distinguished_name      = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions          = req_ext

[ req_dn ]
countryName             = US
stateOrProvinceName     = Chicago
organizationName        = Company Name
organizationalUnitName  = iOS development
commonName              = Internal development CA

[ req_ext ]
basicConstraints        = critical, CA:TRUE
keyUsage                = keyCertSign, cRLSign
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
```

Whereas the end-entity certificate (TLS server) should have these extensions:

```
...
[ req_ext ]
basicConstraints        = CA:FALSE
keyUsage                = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage        = serverAuth
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid, issuer
subjectAltName          = DNS:server2.myserver.local
```

---

> Then I install ca.p12 and certificate.p12 on my IIS server and on my devices.

**Don't install the CA's private key on your devices!** Don't install it on the server, either. You should install *only* the CA certificate `rootCA.crt` (the public part) and nothing else.

---

My final recommendation: Don't waste time trying to make CAs with raw `openssl`. Instead use [Easy-RSA](https://easy-rsa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (the one which comes with OpenVPN), or use [XCA](https://hohnstaedt.de/xca/) (graphical Linux app), or use one of the *possibly dozens* of already written and tested programs.

Comment: Sorry, but I have limited knowledge about certificates. What commands should I type to follow your instructions?

Comment: What commands did you issue originally?

Comment: see my question, please.